# Mysql binlog do not track Xid event after commit one transaction

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently working with mysql binlog. As i knew, when mysql successfully query (like delete, write, update, ..) one transaction which will save an event (`XID`) to mark the success of a transaction. But it didn't happen like that:

[image]

I don't see any `XID event` when i finish insert query. It messed up my bin log process reading.
Why does it happend?

Comment: Is the table an InnoDB table? According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/classmysql_1_1binlog_1_1event_1_1Xid__event.html "An XID event is generated for a commit of a transaction that modifies one or more tables of an XA-capable storage engine." So if the table being modified uses e.g. MyISAM storage engine then it won't generate a XID event.